# Why is there no plain drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

In Android Studio, when a project is created it includes a bunch of `drawable` folders, but each with a suffix indicating their size.

For example, there's

```
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
...
```

However, very often I see instructions to add something to the `drawable` folder. For example, in the Android documentation about `selector` xml resources, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

Should I add a `drawable` folder without a suffix? Or should I add the xml file to all of the different `drawables`? Why is there no plain `drawable` from the beginning?

Comment: In a nutshell, the size specific `drawable` folders are allowing you to target specific resolutions. The generic one, obviously, doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add drawable folder without any suffix for selectors or some nine patch images which you want to be generic but drawable folder without suffix is basically for selectors only.

Android studio or eclipse does not provide it while project creation coz it doesnt know your pre requirement for these thing.

So there is no harm in creating the folder of your own.

while developing in eclipse there was no folder for fonts or xml folder for widget but you can create these folders on your own.

Comment: Do not put 9-patch images (or any non-XML drawables) in the unqualified `drawable` folder. If you don't want the system to scale the image, put it in `drawable-nodpi` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawable folder without any suffix. Also? if you have owner file used on any screen, you can set image to own of any drawable folder with any suffix.